# Select some line in Powershell GET-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need a help

i'm trying to make a script that capture the result of a "GET-ADUser" cmdlet, to put in a variable, but something goes wrong..

The code i'm using:

```
$Name = (Get-ADUser -Identity UserName | FT GivenName)
```

But has result, i recieve:

```
PS C:\> $Name

GivenName
---------
Bruno
```

Anyone knows how i catch only the name on this?
Thanks.

Comment: I presume you are looking for just `Name`, so change `GivenName` to `Name`

Comment: or maybe you mean you want it to return just the name into the variable in that case you want to do `$name = (get-aduser -identity UserName).GivenName`

Comment: Thanks ssaviers. the second answer was what i need.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the following format to select one particular property to be returned from the object and saved to your `$name` variable.

```
$name = (Get-ADUser -Identity UserName).GivenName
```